ChatGPT, Home Assistant, Alexa Integration
I am having Issues with my home assistant webhook that sends the Alexa json to ChatGPT.  I have created a custom Alexa Skill with one intent and a few utterances to "prompt".  My home assistant webhook automation looks like this:
automation:
  - alias: ChatGPT Webhook Dynamic Handler
    trigger:
      platform: webhook
      webhook_id: chatgpt_webhook
    action:
      # Step 1: Check if the payload contains a 'prompt'
      - choose:
          - conditions:
              - "{{ 'prompt' in trigger.data }}"
            sequence:
              # Step 2: Send the 'prompt' to the OpenAI API using the REST command
              - service: rest_command.openai_query
                data:
                  prompt: "{{ trigger.data['prompt'] }}"

              # Step 3: Wait for the response from OpenAI
              - wait_template: "{{ states('input_text.chatgpt_response') != 'Awaiting response...' }}"
                timeout: "00:00:10"
                continue_on_timeout: false

              # Step 4: Save the response for reference
              - service: input_text.set_value
                data:
                  entity_id: input_text.chatgpt_response
                  value: "{{ states('input_text.chatgpt_response') }}"

              # Step 5: Notify the response using TTS
              - service: notify.media_player.office_echo
                data:
                  type: tts
                  message: "ChatGPT Response: {{ states('input_text.chatgpt_response') }}"
                  title: "Webhook Response"

              # Step 6: Notify the response for debugging
              - service: persistent_notification.create
                data:
                  message: "ChatGPT Response: {{ states('input_text.chatgpt_response') }}"
                  title: "Webhook Response"

      # Default action if 'prompt' is not in the payload
      default:
        - service: persistent_notification.create
          data:
            message: "Webhook triggered, but no 'prompt' found in data!"
            title: "Webhook Debug"

Im wondering if someone out there can point out whats wrong in the code?
I have spent countless hours formatting and trying different variations of the base code, but i'm having trouble getting it to work.

What do you mean by "having trouble getting it to work"? What exactly is your output? Do you get error messages? What does the expected outcome look like? Please see [mcve] for more information.

The error I get is is that the webhook doesn't receive any data.  I am sure I have configured the Alexa skill proiperly because when I manually post to the webhook using curl I get that error.

"when I manually post to the webhook using curl I get that error" what error? Or do you mean you don't get that error?

I don't have a copy of the error, but the error states that no data is received and I get that error when I use the curl command to make a post to the webhook.
